# Показ и удаление треков на Yandex картах

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Здравствуйте, у меня вот какая задача есть база треков (набор .gpx файлов), которые лежат в определённой директории на сервере с WordPress. Нужно показать их на карте. html код я генерирую с помощью PHP.

```
<form> <input type="checkbox" name="2014-07-13.gpx" value="2014-07-13.gpx" onchange="showtrack('2014-07-13.gpx',1)">2014-07-13.gpx<br><input type="checkbox" name="2014-06-21.gpx" value="2014-06-21.gpx" onchange="showtrack('2014-06-21.gpx',4)">2014-06-21.gpx<br></form>
```

Под самой картой список checkbox'ов при смене состояния вызывается javascript

```
function showtrack (name,k) {
checkbox=document.getElementsByName(name);
if (checkbox[0].checked==true) {
  ymaps.geoXml.load('http://mkpp.org/geo/tracks/'+name).then(
   function (res,k)
    { myMap.geoObjects.add(res.geoObjects,k);
    myMap.setBounds(res.geoObjects.getBounds());
  });
}
else {
  myMap.geoObjects.remove(k);
}
```

Суть в том, что трек надо показывать только при выделенном checkbox'е. Отображаться отображается, а вот при попытке удалить трек с карты, на `myMap.geoObjects.remove(k);` ругается

> "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Как побороть?

Comment: `console.log(myMap.geoObjects)` что выдаст?

Comment: Добрый день. Возможно, вы пользуетесь ссылкой на несуществующую карту. Или myMap не является объектом карты. В картах яндекса, при создании новой карты, возвращается ссылка на нее. Надо ею и пользоваться.    
var map = new ymaps.Map(/*...*/);    
map.geoObjects.remove(k);     
И теперь надо пользоваться map.